# Running external program that continuously writing text file in php

Tags: php, windows

I'm building a website to monitor network for my office. i'm using Windows 10, XAMPP with Apache and PHP.
I'm using external program that i made in C to monitor the network on my office. The program will continuously write log into text file.
I want to use PHP to open the program and write log into text file, then load the text file into MySQL using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. i tried using `exec();` to open the program. but after open the program, i can't load the text file into database. My webstie hangs and i can't close the program.
here some of my code :
`exec("Monitor");`
I have tried using `> /dev/null &` but it does nothing.

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.txt'
        INTO TABLE table_name
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
        (col1, col2, col3, col4)";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

What can i do to fix this? I want to run server program from client side.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php:

> On Windows exec() will first start cmd.exe to launch the command.

which I believe will cause PHP to wait until execution of cmd.exe is finished.

There are several different method like the first contributed note at thast same page.
Myself used to create a new process using Windows's WMI.

```php
$outputFile       = 'c:/test/logFile.txt';
$append           = false;
$workingDirectory = 'c:/test';

$command = sprintf(
            'cmd.exe /C %s 2>&1 %s %s',
            $command,
            $append ? '>>' : '>',
            $outputFile
);

$wmiService         = new COM('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//./root/CIMV2');
$startup            = $wmiService->Get('Win32_ProcessStartup');
$config             = $startup->SpawnInstance_();
$config->ShowWindow = 12;

$process   = new COM('winmgmts:root/cimv2:Win32_Process');
$processId = new VARIANT();

$processError = $process->Create($command, $workingDirectory, $config, $processId);

if ($processError) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error $processError occurred while creating the process!");
}
```

More info about `Win32_ProcessStartup` can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processstartup